# Web crawler dealing with "Sign up or log in to read full content"

Tags: html, ruby, web-crawler, nokogiri

Given a page like [this](http://www.quora.com/Is-enrolling-in-culinary-school-at-age-40-in-order-to-change-careers-a-ridiculous-idea), I am trying to extract all the answer text with a ruby web crawler.

I am using nokogiri and `search('div[@class="answer_content"]').inner_text` to access the answers, but I can't seem to access all the text, even when in fact I am logged in. About 200 words down, I'll get the message "sign up or log in to read full content."

Also, is this div class the correct one to use?

Comment: When you way "I am logged in", do you mean you, as a user, are logged in, or that you application handles the login server side ?

Comment: How are you fetching your pages? Staying logged in usually requires a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need to authenticate yourself from the crawler. I've done it a few weeks ago. I used a firefox extension called `Tamper Data` which allowed me to see the requests made between the browser and the server. In my case, the authentication was handled by a session id; I just had to get it back and pass it to each request I made to the server.

But in your case, the authentication might be done by a different way, you'll have to see for yourself. Anyway, I can detail if it's not clear enough.

Comment: I think they're using a web beacon. Is that fairly uncommon?

Comment: @ksol is right. You can use http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/ to help you log in programmatically, keeping the cookie